# Cordova 'cordova-plugin-splashscreen' fails to install on android 11

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

While updating android platform within an ionic project to **android 11.0.0** via the command

```
   ionic cordova platform add  android@latest
```

The plugin **cordova-plugin-splashscreen 6.0.2 "Splashscreen"** fails to install

```
    Installing "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" for android
    Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 11.0.0, failed version requirement: >=3.6.0 <11.0.0
    Skipping 'cordova-plugin-splashscreen' for android
```

I am developing for both iOS and Android, any help solving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-splashscreen

Supported Platforms
Android Note: Android implementation has been moved to the core framework. If using cordova-android@10.x or earlier, use cordova-plugin-splashscreen@6.x If using cordova-android@11.x or later and exclusively developing for Android, this plugin can be uninstalled.